# Arbitrum transaction queue STUCK in UI

Tags: gnosis-safe

I have tried to work with the support on the web site.  My safe on Arbutrim only is having an issue and was working for weeks up until about 2 days ago.

My safe in the iOS app shows 24 is latest nonce and through web is 16.

I was told I need to use the safe-cli.

I was told `according to our devs, you are using a wrong master copy (not L2 master copy on L2 network).`

```
You can check it https://safe-transaction.arbitrum.gnosis.io/api/v1/safes/0xdf1441d86fA2b2331eED52569e003e482c90Ef95/ and then with masterCopy go to
https://arbiscan.io/address/0xd9Db270c1B5E3Bd161E8c8503c55cEABeE709552#code . 
Master copy should be GnosisSafeL2, like
https://arbiscan.io/address/0x3E5c63644E683549055b9Be8653de26E0B4CD36E#code
```

In the safe-cli I show that the current NONCE is 23, which is right (I just tried to do another transaction) as nonce 24 still nothing.

Do I need to do `change_master_copy 0x3E5c63644E683549055b9Be8653de26E0B4CD36E` ?

Is what needs to be done to get stuff cleared?   Is there any way to clear the pending transactions in entirety, to be at nonce 25 is the next one?

Please advise

Comment: Everything was working, then now getting error 0026 but nothing changed on my end.

Comment: I know it says that GS026 is a signature error, but the OWNER address are correct and am using those address to sign so really confused.

Comment: Today was told that some changes were made, that makes these nor work right through UI.  Need some help executing a transaction through a DAAP to move all funds from my Arbitrum via the CLI.

Comment: How can I change the MasterCopy to fix this via CLI?  When I try I get an error GS0013